# online survey showing only few questions from database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm having a problem with my project which is an online survey. The problem is that when i login to the survey page where the questions are supposed to appear, only 7 questions shows. the questions are supposed to show after a radio button is selected. after the six question the seventh question keeps showing like a loop instead of all 20 questions which are stored in the mysql database. this is the code that is supposed to show the questions with increments in question id number.

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
require "config.php";

$qst_id=$_POST['qst_id'];
$opt=$_POST['opt'];

if(!is_numeric($qst_id))
{
    echo "Data Error";
    exit;
}

$sql=$dbo-.prepare("INSERT INTO poll_answer(qst_id,opt) VALUES($qst_id,:opt)");
$sql->bindParam(':opt',$opt,PDO::PARAM_STR,50);
$sql->execute();

$qst_id=$qst_id+1;

$no_questions = $dbo->query("SELECT COUNT(qst_id) FROM poll_qst")->fetchColumn();

if($qst_id>$no_questions)
{
    $next='F';
}
else
{
    $next='T';

    $count=$dbo->prepare("SELECT * FROM poll_qst WHERE qst_id=$qst_id");

    if($count->execute())
    {
        $row = $count->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
}

$main = array("data"=>array("q1"=>"$row->qst","opt1"=>"row->opt1"...));

echo json_encode($main);

?>
```

SURVEY PAGE CODE:

```
<?Php
session_start();
?>
<!Doctype html>
<html language="en">
<head>
<title>Welcome - <?php echo $userRow['firstname']; ?></title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyles.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="que">
<div id="ques">
<p id="heading1"><b>UNIVERSITY OF GHANA</p>
<p id="heading">DEPARTMENT OF COMPUTER SCIENCE</p>
<p id="heading">STUDENT'S EVALUATION OF COURSES & LECTURERS</b></p><br><br>
<p id="pps">The purpose of this questionnaire is to offer you the opportunity to assess the lecturer and course being taught. Please select the response that you think is most appropriate to each statement below.</p>

<p>Course Code: <select><option value="1st">CSIT 201</option>
                       <option value="2nd">CSIT 202</option>
                       <option value="1st">CSIT 203</option>
                       <option value="2nd">CSIT 204</option>
                       <option value="1st">CSIT 205</option>
                       <option value="2nd">CSIT 206</option>
                       <option value="1st">CSIT 207</option>
                       <option value="2nd">CSIT 208</option>
                </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
Course Title: <select><option value="1st">COMPUTER ETHICS</option>
                       <option value="2nd">COMPUTER NETWORKS</option>
                       <option value="1st">COMPUTER HARDWARE FUNDAMENTALS</option>
                       <option value="2nd">INFORMATION SECURITY</option>
                       <option value="1st">OBJECT ORIENTED TECH. FOR IT PROFESSIONALS</option>
                       <option value="2nd">APPLIED IT PROGRAMMING</option>
                       <option value="1st">DATABASE FUNDAMENTALS</option>
                       <option value="2nd">MULTIMEDIA AND WEB DESIGN</option>
                </select><br><br>
Semester: <select><option value="1st">1st Semester</option>
                  <option value="2nd">2nd Semester</option>
          </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
Academic Year: <select><option value="2015">2015</option>
                       <option value="2016">2016</option>
                       <option value="2017">2017</option>
                       <option value="2018">2018</option>
               </select><br><br>
Name of Lecturer: <input type="text" size="100"></p>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {

$("input:radio[name=options]").click(function() {

$.post( "surveyck.php", {"opt":$(this).val(),"qst_id":$("#qst_id").val()},function(return_data,status){

if(return_data.next=='T'){
$('#q1').html(return_data.data.q1);
$('label[for=opt1]').html(return_data.data.opt1);
$('label[for=opt2]').html(return_data.data.opt2);
$('label[for=opt3]').html(return_data.data.opt3);
$('label[for=opt4]').html(return_data.data.opt4);
$('label[for=opt5]').html(return_data.data.opt5);
$("#qst_id").val(return_data.data.qst_id);
}
else{$('#maindiv').html("Thanks for your views");}

},"json"); 
$("#f1")[0].reset();


     });


   });
</script>

<?Php
require "config.php";
$count=$dbo->prepare("SELECT * from poll_qst where qst_id=1");
if($count->execute()){
$row = $count->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
echo "
<div id='maindiv' class='maindiv'>
<form id='f1'>
<table>
<tr><td>
<h3 id='q1'>$row->qst</h3></td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type=hidden id=qst_id value=$row->qst_id>
<tr><td>
      <input type='radio' name='options' id='opt1' value='option1' > <label for='opt1' class='lb'>$row->opt1</label>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
      <input type='radio' name='options' id='opt2' value='option2' >  <label for='opt2' class='lb'>$row->opt2</label>
</td></tr>

<tr><td>
      <input type='radio' name='options' id='opt3' value='option3' >  <label for='opt3' class='lb'>$row->opt3</label>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
      <input type='radio' name='options' id='opt4' value='option4' >  <label for='opt4' class='lb'>$row->opt4</label>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
      <input type='radio' name='options' id='opt5' value='option5' >  <label for='opt5' class='lb'>$row->opt5</label>
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>



";
?>
<div style="margin-top:100px">
<a href="logout.php?logout">Sign Out</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[table with questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucsLz.png)

[Table with questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucsLz.png)

Comment: Please put the code in your question and not in an image. And since you're already using prepared statements, why not bind every variable instead of just some...? That's like locking the door, but keeping a big window next to it wide open. And, `error_reporting(0);` defeats the purpose of troubleshooting - enable it instead.

Comment: thanks alot for replying. i tried to post the code but got an error message. il try again. ummmm im very new here  though.

Comment: If you're unable to format it, just put it in the question, and I (or someone else) will edit your question and correct the formatting. But as for your issue, enable error-reporting and let us know what it says - otherwise we're merely guessing.

Comment: I got the code from a website. Here's the URL: http://www.plus2net.com/jquery/survey-online.php.

Comment: Please i dont see an option for editing the question. Should i create another question?

Comment: Still - enable error-reporting on *your own code* and figure out what the exact error is. No, don't create a new question - but you see the "edit" button below your questions (just below the tags).

Comment: when i tried submitting the edited question i am told there are errors in my code. I have no idea what they are talking about. I got the same error the first time i was posting the question that is why i used an image instead.

Comment: I can write the url of the survey here so you see what i am talking about better. What do you say kind sir?

Comment: Wouldn't be of much use, the best course of action is to *enable error-reporting* like I said earlier. Replace `error_reporting(0);`  with [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)
[`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) and see what pops out of that.

Comment: And can you show the output, and your HTML form? To format code here, indent the lines with four spaces, or select/highligt the code and press the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: i replaced the     error_reporting(0);    with what you wrote but the problem is still there.

Comment: here is a url to the result page. its supposed to be populated by 20 different questions but question 7 repeats itself after the 6th question 13 times.  http://isaacb10526719.joshwho.website/result.php

Comment: The error-reporting isn't a magic wand to fix issues, it tells you *if* there are any issues ;-) As for the repeating items, it could be a number of things. How do you loop through this code? I can't see any loops in the current state of the code. Are you sure that the last items actually are different than what's being shown?

Comment: i didnt use a loop. I used Jquery, and yes there are twenty different questions. I will post a picture of the database table.

Comment: I'm not familiar with using jQuery for that, but I'm guessing there's something with your jQuery functions then. Do some basic debugging with `console.log();` and figure out if it's entering the right if-blocks etc, as it seems like a logical/structural issue. -- But wouldn't it be easier to print the values in PHP and just use AJAX to fetch the results?

Comment: Could you help me with that? Printing the values in PHP and using AJAX to fetch the results.